# Python Format string "}" fill

Tags: python, string-formatting

Python 2.6 defines [`str.format(…)`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format), which, from Python 3.0, is preferred to the old `%` style of string formatting. Looking at the "[mini-language](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)", however, it seems that it is impossible to use the `}` character as a fill character.

This seems like a strange omission to me. Is it possible to somehow escape that character and use it as a fill character?

I know I could fill with some unique-to-the-string character and then use `str.replace`, or any number of other similar tricks to achieve the same result, but that feels like  a hack to me…

Edit: What I'm after is something like

```
>>> "The word is {0:}<10}".format("spam")
'The word is spam}}}}}}'
```

Comment: Isn't this like: "Why can't I use \0 in my C strings?" I mean, the question has its right to be asked, but the edge cases where this would matter are really esoteric.

Comment: If it would be `)` and you would auto-generate Lisp code, maybe, OK. But curly closing braces?

Comment: Yes, it's esoteric, and will probably never be used. But I'm allowed to be curious, right? (And \0 in C strings is possible, you just escape the \; it seems strange to me that there is no escape whatsoever available in this situation).

Comment: Unfortunately I've nowhere near Python 2.6 running, but have you tried `"{0:\}<10}"` or `"{0:" r'}' "<10"` yet? I assume it won't change anything (since the docs explicitly say 'no }'), but could be worth a try.

Comment: Could someone please edit the question to correct the part about "old-style formatting from Python 3.0".  Should be "from Python 2.5 and earlier" or something like that.

Comment: @me_and, no, you can't just escape the `\``. @Boldewyn meant `\0` as in the NUL character, the byte with value 0.  Those terminate C strings, so by definition you can't have them *in* your string.

Comment: @Peter: I meant what I wrote; until Python 3.0, the `%` formatting was still the norm. It was only in 3.0 that the preferred format changed to use `str.format`. Point taken about the null character though, cheers.

Comment: @me_and, your edit fixes the ambiguous grammar.  Now it's clear that you mean "preferred since 3.0".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could always specify it as a separate parameter like so:

```
>>> "The word is {0:{1}<10}".format("spam", "}")
'The word is spam}}}}}}'
```

See, it gets passed in and used in place of {1}.